# Having problems with running a JaCoCo test in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jacoco, test-coverage

I want to generate a code coverage report for an Android Java project, but it keeps giving an exception. I had it working once, but then I unfortunately lost that build. I know it is possible and I want to get it working again.

These are the things I did:

I added Jacoco:

```
classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.7"
```

And I put testCoverageEnabled on true.

When I type 'gradlew list' I see the coverage commands. One of them is "createDebugCoverageReport".

When I run that command, it succesfully runs all of the tests which takes about 5 minutes (they are Espresso UI-tests, 30 of them) but at the end it gives an error:

> Execution failed for task '::createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.
> java.io.IOException: No coverage data to process in directories [C:\Git<companyname><companyname>\build\outputs\code_coverage\debugAndroidTest\connected]

I have the following versions:

Gradle 7.0.2

Java openjdk 13.0.2

According to answers online, I should downgrade gradle to 6.1.1. According to [this](https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/compatibility.html) website, a Java version between 8 and 13 is required to run gradle 6.1.1. So I installed java version 13. When I try to sync the project however, it gives the following error:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.1.1.
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

I've been trying to change versions for a couple hours now and I can't figure it out. Does somebody know an answer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.